# which iOS reference has live video playback on iPad mini?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, video

The iPad mini app needs to live display video only uncompressed grayscale 640x480 pixel data through a TCP/IP socket through USB connection from a Windows-7 computer.

Which is the best iOS framework to do this?

Comment: MediaPlayerFramework (`MPMoviePlayerController`) or AVFramework (`AVPlayer`). Both are part of the iOS SDK. Both allow playback of remote video - either progressive download via HTTP or HTTP streaming. Ow, and you certainly do not want to transfer uncompressed video via WiFi as that would result into framerates far below 10 frames per second (even if that is just grayscaled).

Comment: Till: We are using USB not WIFI (Sorry - I just updated question) so this should not limit frame rate, even for uncompressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `AVPlayer` or `MPMoviePlayerController` are baked in and can play video. In your case, I'd recommend [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) because AVPlayer doesn't come with controls (you'd have to implement your own play/pause buttons, scrub bar, etc).

Both implementations will play streaming content or fixed length files. Since you have streaming content, you'll have to format it (transcode it) in a way iOS will understand. This means [HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/).

Converting your pixel data into HLS is by far the hardest part of the problem. There are cloud service providers which can do this such as Zencoder's [Live Streaming service](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/getting-started/live-s3-quickstart). That relies on an incoming RTMP stream, for example from [Flash Media Live Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html).

If you don't want to use HLS for encoding your stream, then you'll have to implement your own video rendering engine in C for your custom pixel data. I'm not exactly sure where to get started with that, but my guess would be somewhere in [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html). Good luck!

Comment: HLS is made easy when using FFMPEG for encoding and segmenting.

Comment: Thanks.  Great answer to get me heading in right direction...especially the heads-up re getting it in HLS format first.

Comment: Thanks @till I didn't know ffmpeg could do un-ended HLS streams.